# Save credential in Flutter from 3rd party page

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter I am using webview plugin to display third-party page on my app. How can I save the credential on my app(logged in 3rd party page), so that session does not expires even after we quit the app and reopen it?

Comment: May be in shared preference, if credential data are small. Or, package like this could also help https://pub.dev/packages/hive

Comment: By "third-party page" do you mean something like a Google sign in or another auth provider that you're signing into?